# RegExp pattern for password must contain letters a-z, A-Z and at least one digit 0-9 and One Special Character

Tags: jquery, regex

I have  written following reg-ex :

```
^(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[@#%$]).{8,16}$
```

to check Password should be of minimum 8 to 16 characters and must contain at least 1 alphabet, 1 number and 1 special character out of @,$,#,%.

But it do not work if  enter special characters like !,^ at the start of the password... please help.

Comment: The 'it does not work' part isn't very clear. Please show us more examples : passwords that are matched and shouldn't, or passwords that should be matched but are not.

Comment: It accepts password like ^^^frank2014$$ which should not be the case

Comment: must it start with n alphabet?

Comment: password match: 1) oliver2014%%,  %%oliver2014, %2ol4liver

Comment: password should not match : 1) ^^oliver2014$$, oliver!!2014$, oliver'"2014$     but its acepting this password this is the problem ... please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should suit your needs:

```
^(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[@#%$])[a-zA-Z0-9@#%$]{8,16}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Visualization by [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/HsYwSHX3Kq59ydPz)

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
^(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[@#%\$])[a-zA-Z\d@#%\$]{8,16}$
```

Comment: it works for password like ^^harrypotter2$ but do not work for  harrypo^^20$$

Comment: No my regex isn't matching both

Answer (score 0):

Your regex will match passwords like `^^^frank2014$$` because of the last part.

```
(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[@#%$])
```

These three lookahead blocks work well to check your first rule : verify if there is at least one digit, one letter and one of the wanted special characters.

```
.{8,16}
```

But this part will allow ANY character in the password, as long as the first rule is verified. That's why it matches passwords with other characters.

That's what you have to change. You could change it to :

```
[@#%$a-zA-Z0-9]{8,16}
```

Final result :

```
^(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[@#%$])[@#%$a-zA-Z0-9]{8,16}$
```

Answer (score -1):

You are remove **first sign (^)** and **last sign ($)** and put this all into  **parenthesis ()** try again,

Use this **Regular Expression**,

```
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@#$%]).{8,16})
```

#### Check this <kbd>**[Validated RegExp](http://www.regexr.com/38m89)**</kbd> and <kbd>**[Check Visually](http://tinyurl.com/ojolxqa)**</kbd>

#### Result

[image]

Hope this help you!

Comment: The anchors may be unnecessary, but they're not incorrect.  Anyway, with or without them your regex still matches invalid inputs like `!1234?AB#cd*`

Comment: ^ ........ $ only means .... with the entire verbatim containing within this two characters ... hence they do not harm ...

Comment: I did explain why.  But I just noticed that you also changed the rules.  The OP wanted to require one or more letter (`(?=.*[a-zA-Z])`), but you require one lowercase **and** one uppercase letter (`(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])`).

Comment: And no, the parentheses do not take the place of the anchors.  Your regex is wrong.

Comment: Now you've changed the title of the question to reflect your mistaken interpretation.  Please, just stop.

Comment: Thank you @AlanMoore i m not know you are take this small kind of issue to give a big. as you like i accept. and i m change title reason is really good question so finding easily via search engine. thats why i chage.